# Как изменять Rotation дочернего объекта относительного родительского?

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Такой вопрос. У меня есть родительский объект *Сфера*, и к нему прикреплён дочерний объект *точка появления снаряда*, но проблема в том, что сфера то крутиться, а получается и дочерний объект тоже. И при движении сферы, снаряды летят в разные стороны, так как точка появления снарядов крутиться по орбите сферы.

Как я могу зафиксировать позицию точки появления снарядов относительно сферы в статичном положении, но чтобы она перемещалась по карте вместе со сферой не крутясь вокруг её орбиты.

*Я просто даже не знаю как загуглить, чтобы самому решить это. Пытаясь кинуть на точку появления снарядов  **Rigidbody**, для того, чтобы зафиксировать его положение; он выпуливает его вместо снаряда, тем самым не имея возможности пускать снаряды.*

Куда копать?

Comment: Прикрепи точку появления и сферу к пустому объекту и крути только сферу, а за перемещение отвечает пустышка.

Comment: @Yaroslav получается сделать их дочерними к пустышке?

Answer (score 0):

сделай и сферу и точку дочерними к пустому обьекту. Тогда перемещать по сцене сможешь этот пустой обьект вместе с дочерними. При этом каждый из них будет независим от второго.